# Mixed Berry Cherry Mead fermentation issue

Tags: fermentation, first-time-brewer, mead, aroma

I'm fairly new to homebrewing, I am making my second batch which is a 1.5 gallon batch. Seeing as how my first batch was very sweet, but not so much alcoholic I decided to make my next batch with more honey to up the alc/v.

The ingredients include 1 gallon of water, 6lbs of honey, 1.5 lbs of cherries, 1.5 lbs of mixed berries(raspberries,blueberries,blackberries), and Larvin k1V-1116 yeast.

The starting gravity was at 1.150.

The first container seemed to be leaking as the airlock was doing nothing, in response I changed the container now my problem is the smell of the must. Last night when I checked it it has a sickly sweet smell to it, but this morning, when I went to stir it for the last time before letting it ferment on its own(if it was even going to). when I opened the lid I was met with a very sour smell almost like vinegar.

Once I put the lid back on it after about 5 minutes the airlock started to bubble every 3-5 seconds, today is the 4th day since I made the batch.

Is it safe to say that the batch is turning into vinegar, or could it just be from the Berries?

The first batch I made had more variety of berries, but only 1 lbs of honey and by the fourth day I was already getting a clear alcohol smell from the must, any advice would be very helpful thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would try a sip and see what it tastes like.

Comment: sniff it, sip it, see what it has become.